# sbt 1.0 simultaneously run and test

Tags: sbt

Pre 1.0 I ran a Main method in one instance of sbt and did integration testing against it in another instance of sbt. With 1.0 I get server already running errors. Do I now have to run the Main outside sbt or is there a 1.0 way to test while running?

Thanks, [laughedelic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736957/laughedelic) bgRun should be more prominent in the docs

Comment: Probably you just need to use `bgRun`? Also those server-related errors shouldn't affect how you use sbt shell.

Comment: For the future, you should use comments to reply. I noticed your edit by accident.

Comment: I also posted it as an answer, so if it solved your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bgRun` to run your application in background and run tests against it. I didn't find any documentation on this feature, but it is mentioned in the [sbt 1.0.0 release notes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html):

> Another related feature that was added is the `bgRun` task which, for example, enables a server process to be run in the background while you run tests against it.